# Laravel - User validation id giving wrong response

Tags: laravel

I have this code in Laravel-8:

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$companyId = Auth::user()->company_id;

$confirmUser = User::where('company_id', $companyId)->where('active', 1)
    ->where(function ($query) use($request) {
    $query->where('email', $request->email);
})->whereNull('deleted_at')->first();
if(!$confirmUser){
    return $this->error('The User already exists', 400);
}
```

If user already exists, I want to:

return $this->error('The User already exists', 400);

carry on with the operation.

> dd($confirmUser); gives null

Yet the postman response is:

> {"message":"The User already exists","error":true,"code":400}

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: change if condition to :  if($confirmUser)

Comment: @YasinPatel - That won't give me the required result. I want to break it there when it's not null., But if it's null, continue

Comment: Yes, and your condition is opposite of it, now if there is record it will break it

Comment: What is weird, is that you will get the error "The user already exists" when it doesn't exist. confusing, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$confirmUser = User::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->where('active', 1)
->where('email', $request->email)->whereNull('deleted_at')->first();

if($confirmUser){
return $this->error('The User already exists', 400);
}
```

Comment: Why would that give a different response? ->first() returns null if the record does not exist...

Comment: What did you change? What was the problem?

Comment: yes, sorry I think use get(). Thanks for correcting me

Comment: I remove empty() in if condition.

Comment: I would change the error message too, this is very confusing :-D .